# Is something wrong in this script?. It is not showing port 53 and port 80 open?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, port

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import socket
from datetime import datetime

#Define a Target

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    target = socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[1]) #Translate hostname to IPV4
else:   
    print("Invalid amount of IP address")
    print("Syntax: Python3 scanner.py <IP>")

#Add a pretty banner
print("-" * 50)
print("Scanning target "+ target) 
print("Time started: " + str(datetime.now()))
print("-" * 50)


try:    
    for port in range(50,85):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
        result = s.connect_ex((target, port))
        if result == 0:
            print("Port is open {}".format(port))
        s.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nExiting Program.")
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print("Hostname could not be resolved.")
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print("Couldn't connect to a server.")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: As it currently stands you just ask for a code review, i.e. you don't show a specific problem which need to be fixed. Code reviews are off-topic. It is not clear from your question that ports 53 and 80 should be open on the destination in the first place. Do you have a specific target where you expect these ports open on TCP and where other scanners used in the same system show that these are open for TCP?

Comment: @ Steffen Ullrich I want to scan ports range from 50-85 in the above script, and I tested it against my home network. As ports 53 and port 80 should be open for DNS and web browser, but after execution there was no result. I have not checked other scanners.

Comment: *"I tested it against my home network"* - whatever this exactly means. But I think you have a failed understanding of networking. Your web browser accesses some remote web server on port 80, so the port should be open at this web server and not in your local network. As with DNS, it is typically used with UDP and not TCP and the only DNS server in your network is likely your router. *" I have not checked other scanners."* - you better should so that you can see that it is not your program which is wrong but your expectation.